# Error when using isReachable() in Android

Tags: java, android, inetaddress

I am a newbie in android development. This is my code

```
boolean isReachable = false;
try{
    isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(MyIPAddress).isReachable(reachableTimeout);
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("InetAddress", e.getMessage());
}finally {
    if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

It works fine when my `AndroidManifest.xml` doesn't have these line

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

And when it has, my app *"Unfortunately, myApp has stopped"*

Could anyone help to to fix it?

My Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(9310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(9310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.thesis.wifihotspot/com.thesis.wifihotspot.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
println needs a message
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:297)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
com.thesis.wifihotspot.MainActivity.setClientsList(MainActivity.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
com.thesis.wifihotspot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE:**
According to this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html),As of Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) StrictMode is configured to crash with a NetworkOnMainThreadException exception, if network is accessed in the user interface thread. So I need to add these codes to make the app works.

> StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
>   ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
>   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Thanks for your supports.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace from logcat

Comment: @Simon Here's my logcat:

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime(9310): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
println needs a message
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:297)
E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at
com.thesis.wifihotspot.MainActivity.setClientsList(MainActivity.java:226)`  What is at line 226?

Comment: `_ClientsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvClients);
  try
  {
   ArrayList<ClientScanResult> _ClientResult = _WifiApManager.getClientList(false);
   _ClientsList.setAdapter(new AdapterForLVClients(_ClientResult,this));
  
  }catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
  };` It is just Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());

Comment: @Simon The method getClientList(Boolean) includes the codes above

Comment: Try `Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage())`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not related to your issue, but you should use `getByAddress` rather than `getByName` if you have the IP Address.

```
isReachable = InetAddress.getByAddress(MyIPAddress).isReachable(reachableTimeout);
```

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29).

**Edit:**

You've got an exception without any message.
First, remove `e.getMessage()`.
Then, show more of your code if you need to resolve your issue.